# No access or ambiguity check on templated member function found in multiple base classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, private, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous

This compiles and runs fine on Visual C++ 2015 Update 3 RC:

```
class A
{
    template <class T> void f() {}
};

class B : A {};
class C : A {};

class D : B, C {};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f<int>();
}
```

There's two problems with this code:

1. `f()` is private, so `d.f<int>()` should fail to compile.
2. `f()` is ambiguous, as it could be `B::f()` or `C::f()`.

However, there's no diagnostic with `/Wall` and `B::f()` is called. Reversing the order `D` inherits from gets `C::f()` called, so I guess it's just using the first base class in the list.

Both g++ and clang get it right. Am I missing something or is this a bug in Visual C++?

Comment: Most certainly a bug. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ef1400b04db2ad7

Comment: Consider submit a bug report here: https://connect.microsoft.com?

Comment: @YuchenZhong I will, just wanted to check if I had something wrong. It's been down since yesterday though.

Comment: Same with update 2 also!

Comment: So you found a bug. Congrats I guess? Not much that can be done here other than upvote.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper It's that kind of Monday, eh?

Comment: @isanae Your question falls under the 'there is no actual problem to be solved: "I’m curious if other people feel like I do."' category from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @sleeptightpupper I'm not sure I understand. My compiler doesn't behave like I expected. How is this about my feelings?

Comment: @isanae I don't see any reason to respond to a strawman argument.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Thanks for dropping by, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with Visual C++. I can reproduce it with 2015 and 2012, but not on 2005. I've opened a [bug report on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2810786/no-access-or-ambiguity-check-on-templated-member-function-found-in-multiple-base-classes). The only workaround I have is to rename the function to have some unusual name so it can't be called accidentally.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on 2017 RC, but intellisense does flag it with a squiggle because it uses EDG. Gotta love it when intellisense is more compliant than the actual compiler.